# json return null from ipage hoster

Tags: php, json, null

I have a code that works well on localhost(xampp kit).
I am using php-oop static classes to generate forms, instead of write html code.
When I use it on iPage server it returns null, for the variable divResposta (html code that will geneate a form - as told above). pkUser,pagOrigem,pagAtual all ok.When I check on inspect elements(chrome)>networks>xhr I see divResposta=null.
Note I use ajax-jQuery to retrive this information.
Any clue will be good.
Thanks

```
elseif($ObjEvn==="link_criarIndicador"){   
    $divResposta=D3BI::Div_Indicador_Criar($idioma,$pkUser);
    $pagOrigem=$pagAtual;
    $pagAtual="criarIndicadorPage";        

    $data=array(
        array(                  
              "divResposta"=>"$divResposta",
              "pkUser"=>"$pkUser",
              "pagOrigem"=>"$pagOrigem",
              "pagAtual"=>"$pagAtual"  
              )
    );
$strJson=json_encode($data);
echo $strJson;    
}
```

Comment: Make sure your `$divResposta=D3BI::Div_Indicador_Criar($idioma,$pkUser);` is not null , if `var_dump($divResposta)` is null then check your `class`.